# Maintaining postfix convention for directives in notebooks

Tags: notebooks, formatting, display

It seems to be a fairly common convention to write certain 'meta' functions in postfix form like

```
f[x] // Simplify
```

to keep the the mathematical content at the front separate from the various directives. However converting expressions to `StandardForm` or `InputForm` converts everything to prefix. Is there a way to get `StandardForm` to use this convention or alternatively is there a form like `StandardForm`, but that uses this convention. I find myself often switching between`StandardForm` and `InputForm` while editing since I prefer to just edit textually using `InputForm` and then convert to `StandardForm` for display, but this makes it impossible to use the above convention.

Reading the documentation I came across `Format` which seems one possible way to do this, but the following does not work:

```
Format[Simplify[x_], StandardForm] := Postfix[Simplify[x_]]
```

Apparently `Simplify` gets evaluated out before this rule is set up. I tried using `Hold` and `Unevaluated` to fix this without luck. This approach would also have the downside of having to define this rule for every function separately and I also do not yet know how I would set up such rules as a default for all my notebooks. So maybe there is a better way.

Comment: `Postfix` is a typesetting function and not the same as `//` in functionality

Comment: @Kuba that throws `SetDelayed::write: "Tag Simplify in MakeBoxes[Simplify[expr_],StandardForm] is Protected"` in my notebook.

Comment: @DanielMahler You are right :) You can `Unprotect` but better not.

Comment: @rm-rf I understand. I want `Simplify` to always appear in postfix position. I do not care that much if the actual expression gets rearranged or if it is just rendered that way, which is what I understand `Format` rules do.

Comment: I think it is impossible to change definitions of how `InputForm` gets formatted. Furthermore `InputForm` works on expressions rather than boxes, so that making a solution based on whether you typed postfix vs prefix seems to be impossible, as the information of whether you typed prefix or postfix is lost when the boxes get converted by `MakeExpression`.